# "He nearly died doing it." meaning in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "... in the end he managed to Apparate out, even though he'd never passed his test. **He nearly died doing it**. Everyone thought it was a really good story, but I was the only one who realized what it meant - ..."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Half-blood Prince</sub>

I think the sentence "*He nearly died doing it*" could mean:

1. He nearly died while doing it(Apparated out).
2. He was trying very hard(probably at any cost) to Apparate out.

I don't know which one is correct. What's it supposed to mean here?

Comment: *In context*, it seems likely he would have tried really hard to "apparate out" (some weird coinage of Rowling's alluding to *(ghostly) apparitions*, I guess). But that's just something you might think because of the context. The words themselves simply assert that "apparating out" was difficult / dangerous, and came close to killing him.

Comment: There is no meaning in this context. It would be the same in any context. It means he almost lost his life.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried to compare to the phrase "die trying" which means trying very hard, but not dying literally. So, I might think "died doing" here along the same line. That's why I was unsure what it meant exactly.

Comment: I'm familiar with the metaphoric hyperbole *He nearly killed himself trying to [do something]* (which doesn't necessarily imply success or failure, just extreme *effort*). But I wouldn't say ***to die trying*** has any significant currency in the sense of ***to try very hard***. Whatever - the example you cite is a straightforward ***literal*** usage (subject really *did* come close to being killed in his attempts to "apparate").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments:

> "The words themselves simply assert that "apparating out" was difficult / dangerous, and came close to killing him." – FumbleFingers

and

> "There is no meaning in this context. It would be the same in any context. It means he almost lost his life." – Lambie

and

> "Whatever - the example you cite is a straightforward literal usage (subject really did come close to being killed in his attempts to "apparate")." – FumbleFingers